# How do I add this pine code in my tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to follow this [article](https://trendlineinvestor.finance.blog/2021/08/01/identifying-stock-strength-through-relative-strength/)
but I'm getting error in using the code given there. Am I doing it wrong? what's the problem?`

```
a = tickerid
b = input(“Nifty”, type=symbol)
as = security(a, period, close)
bs = security(b, period, close)
plot((as/bs)*100, title=”Relative Strength Comparison”, color=blue)
len = input(52)
len1 = input(10)
plot(ema((as/bs)*100, len), color=red)
plot(ema((as/bs)*100, len1), color=green)``
`
[![I've tried doing it this way and getting the error in 7th line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tcG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tcG.png)

I've also tried using it without quotation marks as someone suggested that in comments of the article.

also can someone can help me replicate the output if his code won't work using "rs line" indicator by john muchow as the blog suggests using it.
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` and `shorttitle` arguments of the `study()` are of type `string`. So you need quotation marks around them.

```
//@version=3
study("Relative Strength Comparison", shorttitle="Relative Strength Comparison")

a = tickerid
b = input("Nifty", type=symbol)
as = security(a, period, close)
bs = security(b, period, close)
plot((as/bs)*100, title="Relative Strength Comparison", color=blue)
len = input(52)
len1 = input(10)
plot(ema((as/bs)*100, len), color=red)
plot(ema((as/bs)*100, len1), color=green)
```